# ASP .NET CORE MVC, html - choose default image if user didn't choose any

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want the "Choose file" to be optional. That means if user does not click "Choose file", the default image (/wwwroot/n-image/NoImage.png) is chosen. "Image" is a string property of Article object.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
      <br />
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" />
      </div>
      <span class="text-danger"></span>
      <br />
    </div>

    <img id="FormFilePrv" src="" style="border:1px; top:20px;margin-left:120px;" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Utwórz artykuł" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  document.getElementById('FormFilePrv').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
})
```

Comment: So your javascript changes the `.src` attribute, but you want it to default to `~/n-image/NoImage.png` and change back if the user cancels? hint `if (e.target.files.length)`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman 
If user clicks "Change button" 
       src="path/to/user/image" 
else
       src="~/n-image/NoImage.png"
I want this. Could you edit my code then?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited some code in your view . I set a default Image `117.png` in `wwwroot/n-image` , When the page load , `<img id="FormFilePrv"  src="/n-image/117.png" class="detailImage" />` will display the default Image and if user doesn't choose any image just cilck the `submit` button , `<input type="hidden"   name="ImagePath" id="test" value="/n-image/117.png"/>` will submit the default Image's path .

If user click the `Change button` , the choosen Image will display in `<img.../>` and the value of `<input type="hidden" ...../>` will change to the path of the choosen Image.

**View**

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Show" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label  name="Image" class="control-label"></label>
          <br />
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="Image" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" />
          </div>
          <span class="text-danger"></span>
          <br />
        </div>
    
        <img id="FormFilePrv"  src="/n-image/117.png" class="detailImage" />
        <input type="hidden"   name="ImagePath" id="test" value="/n-image/117.png"/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Utwórz artykuł" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    
    @section Scripts
    {
        <script>
            $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
              var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
              document.getElementById('FormFilePrv').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);      
              $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
              var ImagePath =  document.getElementById('FormFilePrv').src;
              document.getElementById('test').value= ImagePath;
            })
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    }
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Show()
        {
           
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Show(string ImagePath,IFormFile Image)
        { 
          //......
            return View();
        }
```

**demo**

when user click `submit` button directly, the default Image's path will submit to the controller.

[image]

When user choose a Image and click `submit` button , the choosen Image and the choosen Image's path will submit to the controller.

[image]

Comment: I cannot do it like so because I have to use
' <input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" />'
the asp-for="Image" in case user chooses image but at the same time this attribute makes me choose image even I do not want to

Comment: Hi@Jakub Kowal , I try your code ,when I select a image ,the choosen image will display in `<img id="FormFilePrv" src="" style="border:1px; top:20px;margin-left:120px;" />`
.So do you want to when the page loads, the defualt image will display in `<img..../>` , if user don't choose any image and click submit button ,the default image will be submited

Comment: Yes. If user clicks "Change button"  Image="path/to/user/image" else Image="~/n-image/NoImage.png" I want this. Image is a string property of Article.

Comment: If you want to upload file , the type of `Image` in `<input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="custom-file-input" id="FLFormFIle" />`  must be `IFormFile` , you can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I have edited my answer and i hope it can help you.